# Vue.js random color appended to user list everytime page is (re)loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have some jQuery code I want to convert to Vue.js. Basically, everytime I (re)load the page, a random color is given to each user of a list and its different everytime.

Here is the jQuery code:

```
//RANDOM USER COLOR
    $(".usersElements").each(function(index) {
    var idUser = $(this).attr("id");
        if ($.inArray(idUser, usersColors) == -1) {
            var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
            var color = '#';
            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        usersColors.push(idUser);
        colors.push(color);
        $(this).find(".colorsByUser").css("background-color", color);
        } else {
            var index = usersColors.indexOf(idUser);
            $(this).find(".colorsByUser").css("background-color", colors[index]);
        }
    });
```

I forgot to mention and this might be important. The list of users is dynamic and called with PHP.
Here is the HTML:

```
                <div class="col-md-12">
                   <div id="users" name="users">
                   <!--- section to display the list of users starts -->
                        <?php   if(!empty($user))
                        { 
                            foreach($user as $value) 
                            { 
                            ?>
                                <div class="row oddEven usersElements userid" id=<?php echo $value->id;?> style="margin-top: -1vw;">
                                    <div v-on:click="displayAgregators(<?php echo $value->id;?>)" class="col-md-10">
                                        <span id="items<?php echo $value->id;?>"><?php echo ucfirst($value->username);?></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <div class="colorsByUser"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php } 
                        }?>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I have searched for different solutions, but nothing directly related to the problem. 
Hope you guys can help!

Comment: Can you please add the html code . so pleases add the full code will help us to help you out

Comment: i will update then with the HTML

Comment: there is a answer below @Timmy does that solve your issue ?

Comment: I just saw the answear now, i'm testing at the moment. I will tell you in a few minutes :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Vue, it's always just a matter of modeling what you want to display. So you have a list of users, and you have a function to generate a random color. Then it's just

```
<div v-for="user in users" :style="{backgroundColor: randomColor()}">{{user.name}}</div>
```

You can implement your caching of colors by id, too:

```js
const v = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    users: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Alice'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Bob'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Carol'
    }, {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Dennis'
    }],
    colorCache: {}
  },
  methods: {
    randomColor(id) {
      const r = () => Math.floor(256 * Math.random());

      return this.colorCache[id] || (this.colorCache[id] = `rgb(${r()}, ${r()}, ${r()})`);
    }
  }
});

setTimeout(() => {
  v.users.push({id: 5, name: 'Ellen'});
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="user in users" :style="{backgroundColor: randomColor(user.id)}">{{user.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: almost working! The color is appearing but it's not random yet. Also the random color of a user will be the same as another user, even when the page loads and the color changes. I added the html, so you can check, if you like

Comment: Issue fixed! Thanks @Roy J :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vue custom directive

```
<div v-colors>

</div>
```

```
 directives: {
    colors: {
      inserted(el) {
//the current dom element

        el.style.backgroundColor = `#${(
          (Math.random() * 0xffffff) <<
          0
        ).toString(16)}`;
      //  console.log(((Math.random() * 0xffffff) << 0).toString(16));
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can have some pre-defined colours,  and then randomly chose which colour to show

```
<div :class="randomColors"></div>
```

```
data(){
return {
      colors: [
        "red",
        "blue",
        "green",
        "indigo",
        "purple",
        "teal",
        "orange",
        "brown",
        "deep-orange",
        "blue-grey",
        "cyan"
      ],
      currentColor: ""
    }
},

 methods: {
    randomColors() {
      this.currentColor = 
        this.colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.colors.length)];
    },
  }
```

Comment: Got an error `You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function`